# Some List specs2 matcher

Tags: scala, specs2

Why doesn't the following work?

```
Some(List()) must beSome(Nil)
```

'Some(List())' is Some but List() is not equal to 'org.specs2.matcher.ValueChecks$$anon$3@480ba116'

Comment: Have you tried something like:

    Some(List[TYPE].empty) must beSome(List[TYPE].empty)

i.e. explicitly using the type constructor for a list of a given type?

Comment: I confirm that `Some(List[Int]()) must beSome(List[Int]())` works ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

```
Some(List()) must beSome(List())
```

also don't work.

```
 'Some(List())' is Some but List() is not equal to 
 'org.specs2.matcher.ValueChecks$$anon$4@48d1978f' 
 Actual:   List()
 Expected: org.specs2.matcher.ValueChecks$$anon$4@48d1978f
```

So the problem is not `Nil`

We know that what we are really doing is something like:

```
 Some(List()).must(beSome(List()))
```

The problem seems with `beSome`. Let's see what `beSome` is returning:

```
val bl = beSome(List())  // SomeCheckedMatcher[Int]
val bn = beSome(Nil)     // SomeCheckedMatcher[Int]
```

This doesn't seen right since the return type is like were are checking an Option for a Integer:

```
val b = beSome(2)        // SomeCheckedMatcher[Int]
```

And those are not our target types:

```
val myList = List()  // myList: List[Nothing] = List()
val myList2 = Nil    // myList2: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type = List()
```

So, what's wrong?

Looking at the [documentation (Option/Either)](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6.5/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html), you can use `beSome` the folowing ways:

> - `beSome` check if an element is `Some(_)`
> - `beSome(exp)` check if an element is `Some(exp)`
> - `beSome(matcher)` check if an element is `Some(a)` where a satisfies the matcher
> - `beSome(function: A => AsResult[B])` check if an element is `Some(a)` where `function(a)` returns a successful `Result` (note that
>     a `Seq[A]` is also a function `Int => A` so if you want to check that
>     a sequence is contained in Some you need to use a matcher:
>     `beSome(===(Seq(1)))`

The last alternative seems to be our problem here. Note the `List()` is like `Seq`, a function from Int => A. In, our example:

```
val myList = List()                 // myList: List[Nothing] = List()
val func: Int => Nothing = myList   // func: Int => Nothing = List()
```

To fix this we should use a matcher (the third alternative of the documentation):

```
Some(List()) must beSome(beEqualTo(List()))
Some(List()) must beSome(beEqualTo(Nil))

// or 

Some(List()) must beSome(be_==(List()))  
Some(List()) must beSome(be_==(Nil))
```